# Numerical integral fails to converge

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm having trouble evaluating this integral where the integrand depends on a derivative of cosine multiplied by a power law. `q` is strictly non-integer in this case, for example, 3/4 or 0.75.

```
derivC[q_, x_] := 
Module[{s = Ceiling[q]}, 
1/Gamma[s - q] NIntegrate[Derivative[s][Cos][x - u] u^(s-q-1), {u, 0, x}]]]
```

I get the errors that the integral failed to converge and that the integrand evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity.

Specifically, if I do

```
list :=
Flatten[Evaluate@Table[
Evaluate@Table[{x, q, derivC[q, x]}, {q, 0, 2, 0.1}], {x, 0.1, 10, 0.2}], 1]
```

and then try to plot `list` using `ListPlot3D` then these errors show up.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your integral is singular-undefined at `q == 0` and other even integers, but the gamma factor annihilates the result.  Should `q == 0` be excluded, or take a limit as `q -> 0`, or what?

Comment: I actually have an `If` statement there that catches all integer `q`. When `q` is integer there is actually no integral by definition, that's why this problem occurs only for non-integer `q`.

Comment: I don't see any `If`, but in any case, you could just ignore integer `q` in my answer, since it agrees with your `derivC[]` at other values of `q`.

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate by parts first, to get rid of the singularity (integrable when `q` is not an even integer).  This results in the gamma factor losing its singularity at integers as well.  I'll leave it to the OP whether that makes sense in the actual use case, but the chances seem good to me that it's the only way to make sense of integer `q`.

```
derivC[q_, x_] := 
 Module[{s = Ceiling[q]}, 
  1/Gamma[1 - q + s] (Derivative[s][Cos][0] x^(s - q) + 
     NIntegrate[Derivative[s + 1][Cos][x - u] u^(s - q), {u, 0, x}])]

Flatten[Table[{x, q, derivC[q, x]},
   {x, 0.1, 10, 0.2}, {q, 0.1, 2, 0.1}], 1] // ListContourPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
derivC[q_, x_] := Module[{s = Ceiling[q], ep = 10^-6},1/Gamma[s - q]*
NIntegrate[Derivative[s][Cos][x - u] u^(s - q - 1), {u, ep, 1, 2, x}, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]

ListContourPlot[Partition[Flatten[Table[{x, q, derivC[q, x]},
{q, 0, 2, 0.1}, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}]], 3], FrameLabel -> {"x", "q"}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[{x, q, derivC[q, x]}, {q, 0, 2, 0.1}, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}]], 3],AxesLabel -> {"x", "q"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does the partition effectively break up the nested table into 3-coordinate points? also, what do the bounds `{u, ep, 1, 2, x}` mean?

Comment: @Buddhapus 1) I'm don't know(Needs tests), 2) tests for singularities in point 1 and 2 see documentation `NIntegrate`